# How to set timeout using AT commands and ELM327

Tags: bluetooth, can, obd

I'm working on Android app that can read data from CAN bus. The interface I'm using is ELM327. The problem is that this interface uses Bluetooth, so I cannot read all the data from CAN bus because after half a second the buffer is full. The interface is v. 1.4.7, and I am using Bluetooth terminal on Android.

The commands I used:

```
ATZ -> to reset the interface

ATH1 -> set header 

ATS1 -> set spaces 

ATL1 -> Linefeeds on 

ATAL -> Sets long message
```

Then I want to set delay for lets say 1 sec

```
ATST FF -> Set delay to 1 sec

ATSP 6 -> I'm using CAN so this is protocol no 6

ATCM 170 -> setting mask

ATCF 176 -> set filter

ATMA -> Monitor all
```

Using that, there is no delay. Is there any way to slow this down a little bit with, lets say flow control? It is very important because without delay the buffer is full in half a second.

Comment: Why can't you increase the size of the buffer or read the data out faster? I don't think you want to slow down the CAN bus, critical data may be flying by to other controllers and slowing it down may have unwanted side-effects.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to increase size of the buffer in ELM326. This is going to be the Android app so the measurements don't have to be super precise. I need to send about 10 CAN IDs so without delay there is probably no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Read the datasheet for the [ELM327](https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ELM327DS.pdf) to understand the maximum message rate that can be accommodated. There is no buffer (it has only the RX and single message buffer in the chip) in the ELM327, so any buffering is done by whatever MCU they used to manage configuration and BL.

You clearly (from page 12 and page 74 on) should not turn on LF or AL if you want to get the maximum throughput message rate with least buffer utilization.

One has to say, if you really want to investigate the CAN-bus (all messages at high speed) and are not simply trying to do OBD-II codes, you should get a serious CAN-bus analyzer such as the [Microchip](http://www.microchipdirect.com/product/search/all/APGDT002) one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The thing is that I'm doing this app to the electric Car (Nissan Leaf) so there is no standards PID codes like in petrol engines car.

Comment: @MattKopacz, then you need an analyzer designed for the task.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `ATST` only refers to the amount of time the adapter waits for more frames after as the response to an active command, it has no effect on `ATMA`.

Second, with an ELM327 you will not have sufficient buffers to monitor the traffic on a real CAN bus. If you absolutely want to use an OBD2 adapter, then I recommend one of the STN11xx or STN22xx based products, which have much larger buffers.

The ultimate way to analyze is, of course, using a "real" CAN adapter – even a cheap one with a Raspi will do.